# What is the correct configuration for otherName in SAN section of openSSL CNF?

Tags: san

I've searched all over to get the correct format to add the otherName SAN - with no luck.  I'm trying to generate a client certificate to use with FreeRADIUS.

The following work as it relates to DNS and IP:

DNS.1
DNS.2
DNS.3
.
.
.
IP.1
IP.2
IP.3

But the following generates an error:

otherName.1                         = 1.3.6.1.4.1.311.20.2.3;UTF8:xxx
otherName.2                         = 1.3.6.1.4.1.311.20.2.3;UTF8:xxx
otherName.3                         = 1.3.6.1.4.1.311.20.2.3;UTF8:xxx

Here's the error that is generated:

Error checking request extension section req_ext
488E0000:error:11000093:X509 V3 routines:a2i_GENERAL_NAME:othername error:crypto\x509\v3_san.c:571:
488E0000:error:11000080:X509 V3 routines:X509V3_EXT_nconf_int:error in extension:crypto\x509\v3_conf.c:48:section=req_ext, name=subjectAltName, value=@alt_names

Any help will be appreciated.

Thank you